# Running commands on remote machine

Tags: c#, batch-file, wmi, remote-server, wmi-service

I have written a wmi application which runs a batch file on a remote machine.

This batch file writes the output to the directory-string passed to it as  an argument.

When I launch my application, and choose drive C as the output directory, everything works.
But, when I choose a network drive, it doesn't work, for some reason.

(This network drive is the company's users drive, and mapped for each user on the network).

If I run the same exact command (with the network drive) manually from within the remote machine, it also works...

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
connOptions.Username = sUsername;
connOptions.Password = sPassword;
connOptions.Authority = "NTLMDomain:" + sDomain;
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", sHost), connOptions);
manScope.Connect();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

for (int i = 0; i < listOfJobs.Items.Count; i++)
{
   listOfJobs.SetSelected(i, true);
   inParams["CommandLine"] = listOfJobs.SelectedItem.ToString();
   ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
}
```

Example for job strings:

> Working script: C:\Scripts\BatchScript -p C:\Test C:\OutputDir
>
> Failing script: C:\Scripts\BatchScript -p C:\Test U:\OutputDir

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post the code used in order to help people answer your question.

Comment: Let's see some code please.

Comment: @Idanis Can you clarify on your intent here? I'm not sure if it's just me, but I'm a bit confused contextually by your statement. Are you trying to execute a script locally, and log some output remotely? Or are you trying to execute remotely, and log remotely? When you say "If I run the same exact command (with the network drive) manually from within the remote machine", do you mean have physical access to the machine, or are you shelled in?

Comment: @glace Ok, sorry for the confusion. So, I have a batch script, and I have an application which connects to a remote computer, and runs the batch script on it. I also have connection to the remote computer - I'm controlling it via remote desktop. Now These are the cases I run into: 1) I'm inside the remote machine (without my application, just using remote desktop). Then I launch the script and attempt writing the output to drive U - it works. 2) I'm running my application to connect to the remote, I run the exact script and its arguments as before - it fails...hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ImpersonationLevel to Delegate. Impersonate only allows one network hop, i.e. the server can only access files locally or those back on the client. To access a third machine (the network drive) means another hop hence Delegate is required.

Comment: I did, so now I get an exception: `The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from: HRESULT:0x80010010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))`

Comment: I'm guessing there is some kind of update to the user interface after the remote call? Try using a Dispatcher.RunAsync method for the UI element. I'm getting out of my comfort zone now so if you're still stuck, perhaps this needs to be a new question...

Comment: tried looking for a way to do what you suggested, but didn't find it... This shows compilation errors: `var dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
                    });`

Comment: The code you had before was as I think it should be. What I meant was, what happens after the code you have shown? Do you show a message box or update a field on the screen? If so, that code needs to be passed through Dispatcher.RunAsync. This error aside, is your batch file getting run now?